# Generate and send xml on model save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to generate xml from a model and send it to a web service on model save.
I'm sure this is a common case and should be straight forward. Just create a job on after_save callback that generates the xml and sends it to the endpoint.

Since I'm new to Ruby on Rails I'm not to sure how to handle this though. My questions are more about code organization. It's not unlikely that this api connection will be discontinued in the future so I need a clean modular way to get rid of it. Would it be best practice/convention to put this in a separate gem? Can gems actually add jobs to an existing rails queue? Can gems create migrations on install? I'll probably need to add a model to keep track of the api sync. How about dropping a table on gem uninstall? Or should I not use a gem for this at all?

I realize these are broad and basic Ruby on Rails questions but I'm kind of drowning in documentation. I'm just hoping for some examples and/or advice and maybe some pointers to relevant documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Gem installs/uninstalls are unrelated to apps, they live on different level and do not khow anything about your app code, db and so on unless they are loaded.

Gems for rails can provide rake tasks and/or generators, for example you can look into `devise` gem structure on how it does this.

But i'd advise against moving code to a gem before you know you have to, like for example when you need to reuse it in different project.

To reuse code inside single project - use mixins/concerns

Answer (score 1):

In general:

1. don't make it a gem

   - it's an unnecessary world of pain, pretty much always,
   - never make anything a gem unless you intend to use it in the same way in 3+ applications
2. don't extract it into a concern either,

   - it doesn't seem very likely that you'll do the same operation on multiple models, code reuse seems to not be an issue here and you can actually reuse code more efficiently using service classes too
   - a lot of experienced Rails programmers regard this [practice](http://blog.coreyhaines.com/2012/12/why-i-dont-use-activesupportconcern.html) as [concerning](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/), forgive the pun. It seems this view is not shared by the Rails development team, but at least from my experience writing service classes seems like unnecessary complexity until your project grows enough and then you need to refactor a BUNCH of stuff and you realize you would have been better off ditching concerns from the start
   - use a service class instead and delegate the necessary methods to it from the model
   - this will leave you with a clean interface to extract later and will also allow you to use dependency injection if you need to mock your XML service for tests
3. don't tie API requests to model callbacks, there's usually just 2-3 places where you need to do something with the API and a bunch of other cases where that may not be the case, imagine:

   - tests,
   - or if you get a requirement to implement cache column,
   - or a "number of visits" column
   - or a gem like Paperclip that thought that it wanted to add something to the model but changed his mind and instead of that just touched `updated_at`
   - or any such trickery which will make you a grandiose API spammer and a sufferer of VERRRRY slow database updates
4. if you DO tie API requests to model callbacks,

   - then you better make sure that error handling is done properly and that timeouts etc don't rollback or delay your DB operation,
   - best way from my experience is to run these things through `ActiveJob` + [one of the backends](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html) (though obviously not the `:inline` backend and ideally one of the backends which don't use your main database and allow asynchronous job submission - `sidekiq` comes to mind as a candidate)